# NSManagedObjectContext Locked

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two threads operating in my app.

- In the Main thread I update values of keys in entities or gets some rows from Core Data.
- In the background thread I download data from a server.

But some times during update/processing on core data on `[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]`

… I get:

`#0  0x34507c5c in semaphore_wait_signal_trap ()`
 `#1  0x34507f58 in semaphore_wait_signal ()`

```
#2  0x364d573a in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#3  0x35c91a2e in -[_PFLock lock] ()
#4  0x35c91a12 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] ()
#5  0x35c919e8 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) lockObjectStore] ()
#6  0x35c90676 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
```

How does the NSManagedObjectContext get locked? What can I do for this?

Comment: Please accept appropriate answers to your previous questions, this will likely get you more good answers here.

Comment: I also had the same issue. Do you fix it?

Comment: Yes .Make sure same managedobject context isn't accessed on multiple thread at a time.Please look over accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock is part of the normal operation and is not the source of your problem.

Most likely, you have a problem managing the context on the separate threads. Make sure you use a different context for each thread and make sure you don't pass managed objects between the threads. Make sure you merge the contexts before trying to access changes made on one thread from another.

Comment: As i am accessing context only on main thread .so what could be source of problem managing context on single thread?I also merges changes done on context

Comment: The lock suggest multiple threads or at least multiple context accessing the store at the same time. The lock is a `posix thread mutex lock` so you've got multiple access to the store.

Comment: You say multiple access to the store - do you mean the store used by the managedObjectContext, or just the managedObjectContext - I thought two different managedObjectContexts on different threads could have the same store... (I ask simply because I have this same problem, and cannot see where I would be accessing the same context on multiple threads)

Comment: Yes, 2 different contexts on each their own thread can of course access the same store.

Answer (score 1):

Mastering CoreData in multithreaded apps can be difficult. Make sure you create a new NSManagedObjectContext for each thread that uses CoreData. The MOC must be created in the thread where it is used. The MOC itself is not thread safe. CoreData does not lock it for you. If you use a new MOC for each thread you don't have to do the locking. 
In your stacktrace you can see that the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is locked (not the MOC). CoreData does this so that only one MOC can access the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator at the same time.

Comment: i just used MOC on my mainthread only not in background thread.So why is NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is locked?

Comment: I said that in my answer. It guarantees atomic access to it. If it cannot lock it, it means another thread is accessing it, so the current thread waits until it is free again.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  But when it pauses, it looks like only one thread (the one that's go the __psynch_mutexwait) is using it (com.apple.main-thread).  How can I start to figure out where the problem is?